# font-lock for \left and \big in auctex

Tags: auctex, font-lock

I am trying to replicate 
http://endlessparentheses.com/improving-latex-equations-with-font-lock.html
with no success, I get a `"defface for ‘endless/unimportant-latex-face’ fails to specify containing group"` error when I compile my `init.el` and it does nothing nevertheless.

I cite here the elisp code from http://endlessparentheses.com/improving-latex-equations-with-font-lock.html for reconstruction:

```el
(defface endless/unimportant-latex-face
  '((t :height 0.7
       :inherit font-lock-comment-face))
  "Face used on less relevant math commands.")

(font-lock-add-keywords
 'latex-mode
 `((,(rx (or (and "\\" (or (any ",.!;")
                           (and (or "left" "right"
                                    "big" "Big")
                                symbol-end)))
             (any "_^")))
    0 'endless/unimportant-latex-face prepend))
 'end)
```

Comment: You don't show what you tried, so the question is unclear (useless for anyone other than you).

Comment: I just tried copying and pasting that. I don't get the sintax  that the author used :(

Comment: That's not a recipe. Copying and pasting exactly what, and where? Starting with `emacs -Q` (no init file)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is quite descriptive. You are missing the containing customization group in `defface`.

The following code is working with `GNU Emacs 25.1.50.2 (i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.8) of 2016-04-25` and `auctex-11`.

Note, I have just added `:group 'LaTeX-math` in `defface` but I copied the full code here to simplify copy-paste.

```el
(defface endless/unimportant-latex-face
  '((t :height 0.7
       :inherit font-lock-comment-face))
  "Face used on less relevant math commands."
  :group 'LaTeX-math)

(font-lock-add-keywords
 'latex-mode
 `((,(rx (or (and "\\" (or (any ",.!;")
                           (and (or "left" "right"
                                    "big" "Big")
                                symbol-end)))
             (any "_^")))
    0 'endless/unimportant-latex-face prepend))
 'end)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, I was addind random groups with no success

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using AUCTeX, you can customize `font-latex-user-keyword-classes` to achieve the effect you're looking for.  With this code:

```el
(defface endless/unimportant-latex-face
  '((t :height 0.7
       :inherit font-lock-comment-face))
  "Face used on less relevant math commands.")

(setq font-latex-user-keyword-classes
      '(("mathunimportant"
         ("left" "right" "big" "Big" "!")
         endless/unimportant-latex-face
         noarg)))
```

I get this result:

[image]

Check the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-font_002dlatex_002duser_002dkeyword_002dclasses) for details.

Comment: Any notable difference from the answer from Tobias? besides it is more simplified.

Comment: @k76u4vkweek547v7 - `font-latex.el` is the official interface of AUCTeX to `font-lock`, so chances are high that things like disabling fontification, using themes etc. work better if you use it.  Besides, simplicity is always a plus.